# Send Json over websocket with qt5

Tags: json, qt, websocket, qt5

I've tried this

```
QJsonObject pC;
pC.insert("pC","false" "Uab" "CTOMAN" "1" "1" );
a=conexion.sendTextMessage(pC.value("pC").toString());
```

And I should get a response from the server, the problem is most likely in the serialization of the JSON but I have no idea on how to properly do it.

The JSON as declared in javascript and is proven to work is like this

```
var pC = ["false", "Uab", "CTOMAN", 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON you want to get is

```
{
    "pC": [
        "false",
        "Uab",
        "CTOMAN",
        1,
        1
    ]
}
```

You can use `QJsonArray` and then insert it into `QJsonObject`:

```
QJsonObject json;
json["pC"] = QJsonArray() << "false" << "Uab" << "CTOMAN" << 1 << 1;
// Same as  json.insert("pC", QJsonArray() << "false" << "Uab" << "CTOMAN" << 1 << 1);
```

You have to be careful with quotes, if you want `false` as string, then place it between quotes, if you want it as `boolean` type, then do **not** enclose it in quotes. Same holds for numbers, if you want numbers as `integer` then do **not** enclose it in quotes.

```
QJsonObject json;
json["booleanAndInt"]    = QJsonArray() <<  false  <<  1;
json["booleanAndString"] = QJsonArray() <<  false  << "1";
json["stringAndInt"]     = QJsonArray() << "false" <<  1;
json["stringAndString"]  = QJsonArray() << "false" << "1";
```

will create the following JSON:

```
{
    "booleanAndInt": [
        false,
        1
    ],
    "booleanAndString": [
        false,
        "1"
    ],
    "stringAndInt": [
        "false",
        1
    ],
    "stringAndString": [
        "false",
        "1"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, the way i am sending the json is correct then?